# AngularFire 17: TypeError when calling setDoc with an object with DocumentReference

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I've migrated my app from Angular 16 to 17 and since I couldn't use AngularFire 7.6.* with this version of Angular, I've also updated it to version 17.0.0-next.0

However, I started getting lots of type errors, mostly due to the fact that the Types CollectionReference and DocumentReference now both require the type variable **<AppModelType, DbModelType>**.

I think I get the motivation behind this change. Sometimes the app model (**AppModelType**) is different from what is saved in FireStore (**DbModelType**), which would help avoid casting.
But I'm having issues when saving documents that have a reference (**DocumentReference**) due to this now.

For example, I have the model User (**AppModelType**):

```js
type User = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    ...
    congregation: Congregation;
}
```

And in FireStore, the User type (**DbModelType**) is:

```js
export type FirebaseUserModel = Omit<User, 'congregation'> & {
  congregation: DocumentReference<Congregation, FirebaseCongregationModel>;
};
```

But when I try to call setDoc, with the collection:

```js
userCollection: CollectionReference<User, FirebaseUserModel>;
```

I get a type error on the user (**FirebaseUserModel**)

[image: setDoc TypeError]

The setDoc is expecting an object of type Congregation in the `congregation` property, however, it needs to be a DocumentReferences

Though, it looks like to be purely a TypeError, if I @ts-ignore it, the code runs just fine as it used to do in AngularFire v7.

I'm expecting to be able to call setDoc with an object of DbModelType that may have a DocumentReference without type errors.